# Questions about multiple particles 「が」 in a sentence

Tags: particle-が, manga

Here is the sentence said by a boy who had punched a pig in a pen and then being struck by it.

だめだっ...なぐろう**が**けとばそう**が**びくともしやせん

1) Does the first 「が」 work the same function as the second one?

2) Can I replace the first 「が」with 「と」 or 「や」 to list multiple actions: 「なぐろう」 and 「けとばそう」?

3) Based on the understanding the multiple particles in the sentence, I translated like this: 'Even I intend to hit and kick the pig but it's not  afraid of me at all', am I correct?

Comment: related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15963/9831 ・ http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32949/9831

Comment: `it's not afraid of me at all` 「びくともしない」は「少しも動かない」などの意味の決まった言い方です。参考: [Weblio類語](http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%B3%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84) ・ [デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/184028/meaning/m0u/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What he is saying in this sentence is,

> 「だめだっ...なぐろうがけとばそうがびくともしやせん」
>
> Its no good, its doesn't matter if punch
>   or kick him/it nothing affects him/it.

Yes, 「が」is working the same function in this case.

And to answer the second question, you can't replace the first「が」with 「と」or 「や」.

This another way to re-phrase this.

> だめだっ...殴{なぐ}っても蹴{け}っ飛{と}ばしてもびくともしやせん」

This basically has the same meaning, but the way I wrote it does not convey the emotion that the first sentence (your example) does.
The format is Verb「も」verb「も」, Basically, I did this as well as this.

EDIT. The comment from Chocolate, spurred me to elaborate a little more.

「びくともしやせん」does not carry the meaning of being scared, I am gathering that you were referring to [「びっくり」](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E3%81%B3%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8A%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F). In this case the meaning is that what ever you did to it (pig), nothing affected it. Or you could say it would not budge, flinch or move. Hope that helps.

Edit: Request for further explanation.

「殴{なぐ}ろう」 is the volitional verb form of 「殴{なぐ}る」

> ビリーくんがチャーリくんを殴{なぐ}ろうとしたが、友達{ともだち}に止{と}められた
>
> Billy **tried** to **punch**
>   Charlie, but [Billy's] friends stopped him.

「蹴{け}っ飛{と}ばそう」or 「蹴{け}飛{と}ばそう」 (both same meaning) is the volitional verb form of「蹴{け}っ飛{と}ばす」
and is a conjugated verb of 「蹴{け}る」and「飛{と}ばす」.「 蹴{け}っ飛{と}ばす」and 「蹴{け}る」both mean kick in this context of the sentence, but「蹴{け}っ飛{と}ばす」has the image of being more forceful and more powerful. In most case a verb that is conjugated with 「飛{と}ばす」, you are trying to emphasize the effect of the original verb.

> ビリーくんがボールを蹴{け}っ飛{と}ばそうとしたが、足{あし}が滑{すべ}ってこける。
>
> Billy **tried** to
>   **boot** the ball, but he slipped and fell.

Here I am using "boot" as a more powerful word to "kick".

In these cases it is interpreted as **try to do something**. 
Another example.

> ビリーくんが山を登{のぼ}ろうとしたが、足{あし}が滑{すべ}って落{お}ちた。
>
> Billy **tried** to **climb** the mountain, but slipped and fell.

By its self you can do this.

> ビリーくんが「あの山を登{のぼ}ろう」、とみんなに言{い}った。
>
> Billy said, **lets climb** that mountain.

In this case it means **lets do something**.

「びくとも・しない」、with out getting too deep, it basically means to not budge, unyielding. 
It will always be「びくともしない」, you can't say this 「びくともする」.
I hope that helps.

Comment: Could you please breakdown the なぐろうがけとばそうがびくともしやせん sentence so a beginner can learn from it? The only word i manage to found was なぐろう. I can't seems to understand けとばそう and びくともしやせん.thanks :)

Comment: @Alice28, I edited the post for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @Alice28, let me know if you are still having trouble with this?

Comment: @Alice28 けりとばす is a compound verb (複合動詞), and けっとばす is 促音便 of けりとばす. See [「蹴り飛ばす」 in 実用日本語表現辞典](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E8%B9%B4%E3%82%8A%E9%A3%9B%E3%81%B0%E3%81%99): 「物を蹴って飛ばすこと。・・・ 『 **蹴飛ばす』とも言い** 、促音便で『蹴っ飛ばす』と言うことも多い。」　
For the change of 「びくともしない」->「びくともしやせん」, see: [What does the word してやせん mean?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24661/9831)

Comment: @KyloRen's thank you very much for your effort to add the details in the answer, yes i now able to grasp the concept much better :)